# mysql_real_escape_string not working on jquery load

Tags: php, jquery, mysql-real-escape-string

This is very strange, but when I add the mysql_real_escape_string it doesn't load the page, this is the code that I load like this:

```
$('.abandalink').click(function(){  
    var codigo_membro = $(this).attr('codigomembro');
    $('#change').load('membrosbanda.php?codigo='+codigo_membro); 
});
```

And this is the membrosbanda.php

```
$id=$_GET['codigo']; 
$conexion=mysql_connect(HOSTNAME,USER,PW) or  die("Problemas en la conexion");
mysql_select_db("bandasideral4",$conexion)  
  or  die("Problemas en la selección de la base de datos");
$registros=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM abanda where codigo='$codigo'") or
  die("Problemas en el select:".mysql_error());
```

if I add 
$id=$_GET['codigo']; 
to $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['codigo']);
it stops working

Comment: in what way does it "stop working"?

Comment: Your MySQL is listening on port 3306 and you just posted your host (ip), username, and password. I just logged in to test it only. You should change your password **asap**

Comment: jeroen is right in his answer, but it would be even better to use prepared statements using PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: @GolezTrol I completely agree...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to connect to a database first, before that `mysql_real_escape_string`is not available.

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php):

> Note:
>
> A MySQL connection is required before using mysql_real_escape_string()
>   otherwise an error of level E_WARNING is generated, and FALSE is
>   returned. If link_identifier isn't defined, the last MySQL connection
>   is used.

Answer (score 0):

If you puts codigo in $id, your sql must be SELECT * FROM abanda where codigo='$id'

a better style would be this: 
$id_s =mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['codigo']);

So you have all your *_s variables being escaped for sql stuff, and all normal variables being tainted data.